# Pass argument to function when clicking pushbutton QT

Tags: c++, windows, qt

Just started out with Qt (and C++ for that matter), and haven't got really used to the SIGNAL/SLOT system.

I have simplified my code down to this:

```
int main()
{
int number = 1;
int * numptr;
numptr = number;
connect(ui.pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(start(numptr);
}
```

I have a button called 'pushButton' that when pushed, I want it to start a "start" function that takes an integer pointer as an argument.

```
int start(int * number)
{
// Do something with the number
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
How can I call function **start** and pass the number pointer as a parameter when the pushbutton is clicked?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way will be to connect to a [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function and capture the numptr:

```
connect(ui.pushButton, &QPushButton::clicked, [numptr](){
    // Do something with the number
});
```

Comment: True. I didn't notice the OP was calling it from main. Notice that the OP also uses `this` in their own code. I'll remove it from mine.